# How to read data from GPS Device (TK06A)

Tags: java, gps, hex

I am a newbie into GPS application and i am stuck with one of the project. I want to read data (Lat / Long) from this GPS device (TK06A). For the time being i am using Hercules SETUP Utility bu HW-group. The data in text format is just garbage while if i convert it to HEX it appears as following

```
{78}{78}{0D}{01}{03}{55}{48}{80}{00}{03}{53}{63}{00}{15}{2E}{44}{0D}{0A}
{78}{78}{0D}{01}{03}{55}{48}{80}{00}{03}{53}{63}{00}{15}{2E}{44}{0D}{0A}
{78}{78}{1F}{12}{0F}{09}{17}{11}{26}{06}{C8}{01}{FD}{4D}{C0}{07}{EC}{09}
{E8}{00}{34}{71}{01}{94}{1B}{00}{BE}{00}{34}{E6}{00}{15}{35}{7C}{0D}{0A}
```

While the HEX data makes certain sense as per the protocol, i am unable to understand the lat / long from this. This is the link to the protocol manual as given by the vendor

[Link to Protocol Manual for GPS Tracker TK06A](http://www.getacoder.com/data/projects/164161/TK06A%20NEW%20device%20protocol%20reference-1.pdf)

I have also tried to write a JAVA code to read the TCP port and print the same but again it was of no help.

Comment: The manual is pretty clear about the protocol. {78}{78} is start of package, then you have 1 byte content-length and 1 byte content-type. What you are looking for is {10} for that content type ... if you find one, read as many bytes as the first byte after {78}{78} tells you. Then you can follow the instructions for GPS - Content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have received the packet as below :

Login string : 78780d0103554880249067690016bd720d0a

7878 - Start bit
0d - Length
01 - Protocol no.
0355488024906769 - IMEI
0016 - Serial number 
bd72 - CRC 
0d0a - Stop bit

Data string: 78781f120f0b050e2536c601fb782d07ed996b00345d01941b00b8002f51001634210d0a

7878 - Start bit
1f - Length of data
12 - Protocol no.
0f0b050e2536 - Time and date

c6 - GPS info length/number of satellites involved in locating. 4-bit - GPS length. 4-bit number of satellites.

01fb782d - Latitude
07ed996b - Longitude

00 - Speed
345d - Status/Course

0194 - Mobile Country Code
1b - Mobile Network Code
00b8 - Location Area Code
002f51 - Cell Tower ID

0016 - Serial information
3421 - Error checking
0d0a -Stop bit

Note: Before using the above hex data convert it into decimal for each parameter.

Let me know if this helps or any other help is required :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for the late reply